# Custom tab name generating PDF using JsPDF

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf

I am generating the pdf in a new tab using *`doc.output('dataurlnewwindow')`*
But I dont like the following naming for my new tab.

> data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovTWVkaWFCb3ggWzAgMCA1OTUuMjggODQxLjg5XQovQ29udGVu.......==

Is there a way I can specify a custom name for the tab title ?

Answer (score 0):

What you see on the utl does not represent the name but **the format of the image** that is loaded on the page at the **base 64**. You do not have to modify it at the risk of corrupting the image